# MPMoviePlayerController leaks memory on init?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

I am using Xcode 4.3.1 with an ARC iOS (5.1) project and appear to have (according to instruments) a memory leak on the following:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
```

I have tried player as a property, ivar - with and without a video file, on a button click etc, etc yet this one line shows as a leak?

Am I missing something really obvious here? I have attached a screen of the leak.

[Leak http://www.webelectrix.com/leak.jpg](http://www.webelectrix.com/leak.jpg)

Thanks,

Comment: I don't suppose you figured this out have you?  I'm encountering the same issue.  Thanks.